# Node.js req.params.locationid not grabbing ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following url with a special ID in it:

```
http://localhost:3000/location/5733e37adcba0f6d5aa88cf5/review/new
```

which is a page with a form that will be filled out and submitted to an api and saved in my database. The strange problem I'm having is that in my controller, the

```
req.params.locationid
```

is returning `undefined` for some reason.

Here's my controller code:

```
module.exports.doAddReview = function(req, res) {
    var requestOptions, path, locationid, postdata;
    locationid = req.params.locationid;
    console.log("\n>>>> " + req.params.locationid + " <<<<\n");
    path = "/api/locations/" + locationid + '/reviews';
    postdata = {
        author: req.body.name,
        rating: parseInt(req.body.rating, 10),
        reviewText: req.body.review
    };
    requestOptions = {
        url : apiOptions.server + path,
        method : "POST",
        json : postdata
    };
    request(requestOptions, function(err, response, body) {
        if (response.statusCode === 201) {
            res.redirect('/location/' + locationid);
        } else {
            _showError(req, res, response.statusCode);
        }
    });
};
```

Any idea why `req.params.locationid` works well in my other controllers, but in this one it's not for some reason? Could my router possible be wrong?

btw, the form is as follows:

```
action="", method="post", role="form"
```

and router:

```
/* Locations pages */
router.get('/', ctrlLocations.homelist);
router.get('/location/:locationid', ctrlLocations.locationInfo);
router.get('/location/:locationid/review/new', ctrlLocations.addReview);
router.post('/location/:locaitonid/review/new', ctrlLocations.doAddReview);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have typing error in router file.

```
router.post('/location/:locationid/review/new', ctrlLocations.doAddReview);
```

Comment: Hah, I looked over that so many times, I guess sometimes you just need another eye. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome :) If it helped, then accept it as an answer.

Comment: I will, but I must wait 10 min to do so. :D

Comment: Haha, I did not know that. Sorry for being desperate for reputation.